# calculate milliseconds with timer Tick in c#

Tags: c#, timer, milliseconds

I want to display milliseconds in label with Timer_Tick event. But even if i initialize the Timer.interval to 1, I cant get the actual millisecond.

Comment: The milliseconds of what? The time between when you started the timer and now? Or the number of milliseconds since midnight? Or the number of milliseconds since Apollo 11 launched?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you want to program, please ?

Comment: actually i want to create a stopwatch, so when clicking the startStopwatch button, i want to increase millisecond as well as second and minute. changing minute according to second is easy but synchronizing second with millisecond is where i got confused! what should be the timer interval?and after how much increase in millisecond should i increase second? i'm a newbie so it seemed confused to me! is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 3):

Windows and C# are not created to be a realtime environment. A timer is not guaranteed to trigger on the exact millisecond that is set in the properties.

Aside from that, the typical LCD displays, nowadays run on 60 Hz. So you get a refresh interval that is larger as 1 millisecond. This means you cannot display milliseconds in a label on a display that has a refresh rate smaller as 1000 Hz.

Comment: **a)** you can set the priority of a process to "real time". Of course this should be done with care. **b)** it IS possible to setup a ticker that is called 1000 times per second. **c)** You can also send 1000 updates per second to the graphics driver. But of course, like you say,  the screen updates only at 60Hz, so from 1000 screen changes, only 60 will be actually displayed. The other 940 will be skipped.

Comment: not exactly what i expected :D but thanks anyway guys!!

Comment: @SQLPolice, you can set the priority to "real time", but that does not turn Windows into a realtime OS (the message pump is still used to trigger the Timer). Neither will it change the nature of .Net that is not designed to be realtime (GC's, etc).

Comment: @GvS of course, your ticker unction will never exactly tick at 1 ms; but your function can call a system function which delivers the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

Had you better explained what you wanted to do in your question, I think you would have received better answers!

So you want to create a stopwatch.

The way to do this is to use `DateTime.Now`, which returns the current date and time. When the Start button is clicked, you save DateTime.Now for later use:

```
private DateTime startTime;

private void StartButton_Click(...)
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Then, every now and then, you need to refresh the time shown in your label. You already have a `Timer` with an interval set to 1. This won't fire every millisecond; the interval is approximate. But this is not a problem!

```
private void Timer_Tick(...)
{
    TimeSpan timeElapsed = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    timeLabel.Text = timeElapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000");
}
```

So you don't rely on how often the event is fired. You simply calculate how much time has elapsed since you started the timer!

There are many ways you can display the resulting `timeElapsed` value. Check out the `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds` and `Milliseconds` fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a stop watch, then you might want to use the class [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx). Have a look at that page, it contains a sample program.

The `Stopwatch` class has methods `Start()`, `Stop()` and `Reset()` to start/stop/reset measurement. And you can use the `Elapsed` or `ElapsedMilliseconds` to get the time measured so far.

Regarding the resolution of the Stopwatch class, MSDN says this:

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the
>   underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating
>   system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the
>   Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise,
>   the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use
>   the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision
>   and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

BTW: on my system the flag `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution` is set to **true**, and `Stopwatch.Frequency` returns a value of **3215342** (ticks per second) which is enough to measure microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

As others posted, you do not get a ms-exact time when waiting for timer events in Windows. You may however, measure the elapsed time between timer events very exactly. The usual way of doing this is to use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.